# node js callback not worked with define function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, anonymous

This is simnple `findOne()` method code with node and mongo

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/blog', function(err, db) {

    if(err) throw err;
    var users = db.collection("users");
    var query = { '_id' : 'bhavin3052' };

    function getData (err, doc){
        if(err) throw err;

        console.dir(doc);

        db.close();
    }

    users.findOne(query, getData(err, doc));


    /*db.collection('users').findOne(query, function(err, doc) {
        if(err) throw err;

        console.dir(doc);

        db.close();
    });*/
});
```

when I call to getData() getting 'err' not define...which works perfectly fine with anonymous function callback.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`users.findOne(query, getData);`

.findOne need query and callback, but you take query and result of getData (result is "undefined").

Answer (score 0):

`users.findOne(query, getData);`

You need to pass the function object (`getData`) into the `findOne` function. If you do this:

`users.findOne(query, getData(err, doc));`

you call `getData` with undefined arguments and pass the *result* of the call to `findOne`.